# Flip SVG object using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm facing a problem when I was trying to flip an SVG object using javascript. I have searched for several methods to flip the svg object direction like:

```
<g id = "object1" transform = "scale(-1,1) translate(-100,0)">
//code of svg object
</g>
```

When I was trying to apply similar code in my js file, it failed to flip the object.

```
svgdoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
var node = svgdoc.getElementById("object1");
node.onclick = function(){
  node.style.setProperty("scale", "(-1,1)",null);
  node.style.setProperty("translate", "(-100,1)",null);
}
```

p.s. the svg object is coded in the .svg file and the above js code is coded in another .js file

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.setAttribute` instead of `.style` for SVG elements.

Although they both are DOM nodes, SVG elements use [inline attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute) for these operations.

Apart from that you also need to `translate` your item to counteract the positional change when scaling is applied

```js
document.querySelector('#group').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(-1, 1) translate(-100, 0)')
})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 195 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g id="group" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5">
     <circle cx="0" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="20" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="60" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="80" cy="25" r="15"/>
     <circle cx="100" cy="25" r="15"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: And (as you did in your code), both `scale` and `translate` are components of the `transform` attribute, they’re not independent attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use style for svg elements too. But there is no CSS property called `scale` or `translate`.
These functions are part of the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property, which is also present as an [SVG attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) like set in your markup, with a slightly different syntax, e.g, CSS does need an unit to work, and doesn't understand SVG's magic [no-]unit.

Since CSS styles do take the priority over corresponding attributes, you don't need to modify your attributes and simply modify your code so that you set the CSS `transform` attribute to both the functions you were trying to set, but this time as a single string-rule:

```js
var node = document.getElementById("object1");
node.onclick = function(){
  // set both functions as a single rule.
  node.style.setProperty("transform", "scale(1,-1) translate(0px,-400px)",null);
}
```

```css
#object1{
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="100" height="100">
<g id = "object1" transform = "scale(-1,1) translate(-400,0)">
<path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"
        fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</g>
</svg>
```